# Шрифт в верстке

Tags: html, html5, yandex-maps-api

Сделал карту yandex а над ней контент
почему то после загрузки карты шрифты поверх нее искажаются и становятся немного мутными, как пофиксить?

Скинул 2 картинки одного и того же текста до и после загрузки
[image: до прогрузки][image: после прогрузки]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
https://jsfiddle.net/pdxe38ot/1/
```

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
    var myMap;

    function init(){     
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 7
        });
    }
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
 }
 .content{
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 400px"></div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="block">
    Текст
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" style="position: absolute;left: 100px;">
   <div class="block">
    Текст
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="endtext">Текст</div>
```

Comment: нужен пример страницы и шаги, где это увидеть

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pdxe38ot/1/ вот здесь второй текст на карте мутный справа